# Can I send an email with an optional Email-field (Wordpress Contact-Form-7)?

Tags: wordpress, email, contact-form-7

On my wordpress page there is a formular where a user can sign in for events. Now the user should decide if he/she would like to add an email adress. Only when an email is given the plugin should send an email.

formular:

```
<label>Firstname:</label>
[text* firstname class:form-control]

<label>Lastname:</label>
[text* lastname class:form-control]

<label>Email:</label>
[text email class:form-control]

[submit "Sign in"]
```

The problem now is that I cannot add the `[email]` attribute on the email tab. I get only a configuration error, because the field must not be empty.

The only solution I can think of is to make the email field required and fill the field with a default value before sending using Javascript. Is there a better way to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

The form validation is there for 98% of the WordPress users, that without this could have issues building forms with the CF7 plugin.  For those that understand the possible errors, or can write their own functions, it's somewhat of an annoyance.

You can turn it off by using

`define( 'WPCF7_VALIDATE_CONFIGURATION', false );` in your wp-config.php

or

`add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_configuration', '__return_false' )` in your functions.php